# Can Ubuntu run a 4k Monitor with current driver for Kaby Lake HD 630 graphics?

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, 4k-monitor

Can Ubuntu run a 4k monitor with the integrated HD 630 graphics processor on the Kaby Lake i5? Specifically what is the state of open source driver development? Since Kaby Lake is so new (at the time of this post), it occurs to me that drivers may not yet support 4k. I am aware that even running correctly, the iGPU won't allow for gaming and that's fine.

Comment: Just FYI, don't even think about trying it without Ubuntu 16.10 and a bleeding-edge kernel.

Comment: Thanks @AndroidDev. So no 16.04 I suppose? Is there a resource out there that I can use to keep apprised of driver development?

Comment: What I would do is just try the live session and see if it works. If not, no harm done.

Comment: Ah, I should have clarified. I don't actually own a 4k monitor. I might buy one but not until I know whether or not I can use it. Is there a chance of the 16.04 kernel getting patched in the future? I like my LTS stability.

Comment: In one week most probably the stable HWE stack kernel 4.8 and matching drivers (mesa) will be released alongside the final release of Ubuntu 16.04.2 ... but if everything works properly, you'll have to try out ! :)

Comment: Alright thanks. You guys were very helpful! Honestly I'm gonna let someone who already has a 4k monitor try this out. I'll post an answer if I hear any concrete news.

Comment: Short answer is yes. Latest Dell XPS13 Dev Edition is 4K and comes with Ubuntu pre-installed.

Comment: @dobey [The latest Dell XPS 13 with Ubuntu](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/xps-13-9360-laptop/pd?3x_nav=OS_BRAND%3DUBUNT&3x_page=1&filterCollapsed=true) is either 1080p or QHD+ (3200×1800), not 4K, but close enough.